# JavaScript Array is getting overwritten

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty

i have a `Smarty foreach` loop where inside it i try to push to a `JavaScript array` named `arrayPorperties`. But the content of the `arrayPorperties` is only getting the last value of all previous values are getting overwritten. Any Solutions?

Note: the `assign` must be done inside the loop, cause it is getting values from the Smarty array `user_properties` otherwise it wont work

```
<script type="text/javascript">user_properties = [];</script>
{​​​​​​​foreach from=$user_properties item="user"}​​​​​​​
    {​​​​​​​assign var='tmp_coords' value=$user->get_coords()}​​​​​​​
        <script>
            user_properties.push(
            ['{$tmp_coords[0]}', '{$tmp_coords[1]}', '{$user->get_name()}', '{$user->get_id()}']
            )
        </script>
{​​​​​​​/foreach}​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Your code seems like it works fine. Can you post your results? and also the `$user_properties`

Comment: Please post a `view-source` from the browser of the loop

Comment: Is this a Smarty problem, or a JS problem? What have you tried to debug which parts are going wrong?

Comment: @NicoHaase This is a Smarty problem, the JS should be fine.

Comment: Then please edit your question to contain more information. How should the generated JS look like? If you know how the result should be, why not change the Smarty code to generate that markup?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.

but i dont have test environment. maybe you need to use JSON.Parse after that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user_properties = '{ldelim}{$user_properties}{redlim}';
</script>
```